# can't find + button on source control in vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm following guide provided by microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-03

but the problem is that I can't add new git repository on vscode. 
I can't find + button though tutorial show...
how can I solve this problem?

[image: ub]

Answer (score 0):

The Source Control presentation has slightly changed since March 2020.

You need to add then select a folder which does not have a Git repository, in order to be able to initialize it: that is what the + was for: a `git init`

What you see (when you add a folder which is not tracked by Git) is:

[image: VSCode init repo]